# Dynamic Regular Expression Generation in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to make my regular expression generic by using parameters. However, the RegExp does not work when I use variables:

The below regular expression works properly where I limit my input to 7 characters.

```
var specialCharactersValidation = new RegExp(/^[a-zA-Z0-9]{7}$/);
```

But when I make it generic:

```
var characterCount = parseInt(attrs.limitCharacterCount); // Value is 7 and type is int
console.log(characterCount); // Value is 7
var specialCharactersValidation = new RegExp(/^[a-zA-Z0-9]{characterCount}$/);
```

This is the console for the above code. The regex does not compile with the character count.

```
7
requestShipmentDirectives.js:73 /^[a-zA-Z0-9]{characterCount}$/ false
```

This does not work. And neither does the below one:

```
var characterCount = parseInt(attrs.limitCharacterCount); // Value is 7 and type is int
console.log(characterCount); // Value is 7
var specialCharactersValidation = new RegExp("/^[a-zA-Z0-9]{"+characterCount+"}$/");
```

This is the console for above code:

```
7
9requestShipmentDirectives.js:73 /\/^[a-zA-Z0-9]{7}$\// false
```

`RegExp` compiles but never works.

The output is always `false`.

Is there anything missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use the `RegExp` without `/.../` to allow the use of variables in a regular expression, e.g.:

```
var specialCharactersValidation = new RegExp("^[a-zA-Z0-9]{" + characterCount + "}$");
```

And double-escape special characters inside.

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp):

> The literal notation provides compilation of the regular expression
>   when the expression is evaluated. Use literal notation when the
>   regular expression will remain constant. For example, if you use
>   literal notation to construct a regular expression used in a loop, the
>   regular expression won't be recompiled on each iteration.